# How to use paginate() with a having() clause when column does not exist in table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a tricky case ...

Following database query does not work:

```
DB::table('posts')
->select('posts.*', DB::raw($haversineSQL . ' as distance'))
->having('distance', '<=', $distance)
->paginate(10);
```

It fails with message: column distance does not exist.

The error occurs when paginate() tries to count the records with

```
select count(*) as aggregate from {query without the column names}
```

As the column names are stripped, distance is not known and an exception is raised.

Does somebody have a work around to be able to use pagination is this case ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the query produced?

Comment: What if you create a view for this query and use that with a where and the pagination method?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5515#issuecomment-54933061

Comment: the fix: https://github.com/alprs/laravel-framework/commit/6f0e55d3f5368af70817204d347dfeb89e700a03

Comment: May be i am missing something, but why you are using `having` instead of `where`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can calculate the distance in the `WHERE` part:

```
DB::table('posts')
    ->whereRaw($haversineSQL . '<= ?', [$distance])
    ->paginate(10);
```

If you need the `distance` value in your application, you'll have to calculate it twice:

```
DB::table('posts')
    ->select('posts.*', DB::raw($haversineSQL . ' as distance'))
    ->whereRaw($haversineSQL . '<= ?', [$distance])
    ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is somewhat of a problem with the query builder as all selects are discarded when doing an aggregate call (like `count(*)`). The make-do solution for now is to construct the pagniator manually.

```
$query = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(DB::raw('(c1 - c2) as distance'))
    ->having('distance', '<=', 5);

$perPage = 10;
$curPage = Paginator::getCurrentPage(); // reads the query string, defaults to 1

// clone the query to make 100% sure we don't have any overwriting
$itemQuery = clone $query;
$itemQuery->addSelect('posts.*');
// this does the sql limit/offset needed to get the correct subset of items
$items = $itemQuery->forPage($curPage, $perPage)->get();

// manually run a query to select the total item count
// use addSelect instead of select to append
$totalResult = $query->addSelect(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))->get();
$totalItems = $totalResult[0]->count;

// make the paginator, which is the same as returned from paginate()
// all() will return an array of models from the collection.
$paginatedItems = Paginator::make($items->all(), $totalItems, $perPage);
```

Tested with the following schema using MySQL:

```
Schema::create('posts', function($t) {
    $t->increments('id');
    $t->integer('c1');
    $t->integer('c2');
});

for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    DB::table('posts')->insert([
        'c1' => rand(0, 10),
        'c2' => rand(0, 10),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Did you tested your query? not working. however, My one working. I know, my one is not good for huge amount of results.To improved query, I have tried to used skip(), take() but failed because of having clause.

Comment: I can down vote your answer but i didn't because at least you tried. however, working example got down-vote :(.

Comment: I know this 2 years old, but I have the same problem. I tried your solution in Laravel 5.5 but it states `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::getCurrentPage()`. Any advice?

Answer (score 7):

This is not a satisfying answer, but if you only need to display simple "Next" and "Previous" links in your pagination view, you may use the `simplePaginate` method. It will perform a more efficient query and it won't crash if you use `having`.

```
DB::table('posts')
->select('posts.*', DB::raw($haversineSQL . ' as distance'))
->having('distance', '<=', $distance)
->simplePaginate(10);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way and also works with links:

```
        $curPage = \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage();
        $total = $model->get()->count();
        $items = $model->forPage($curPage, $showPerPag)->get();
        $paginated = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($items, $total, $showPerPage, $curPage, ['path' => request()->url(), 'query' => request()->query()]);
```

Comment: actually most valuable answer from above

Answer (score 5):

Using Eloquent, I know you can pass columns to the paginator, something like this:

```
Post::having('distance','<=', $distance)
   ->paginate(10, array('*', DB::raw($haversineSQL . ' as distance')));
```

Not sure if it works without Eloquent, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Hypothetically this should work, but it's running the logic twice. In that case it's easier to just do that in the original having clause, so instead of saying having "distance" you would just say having $haverzineSQL < $distance.

Comment: This doesn't work with Laravel 6.20

Answer (score 2):

This is scope implements a **Haversine formula** search, with additional optimization for speed, which is [documented here](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/).

I wish there was a cleaner way to get raw SQL from the query object, but unfortunately `toSql()` returns SQL before the placeholders have been substituted, so I relied on several `*Raw` calls. It's not too bad, but I wish it was cleaner.

The code assumes you have columns `lat` and `lng` in your table.

```
const DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETERS = 111.045;
const DISTANCE_UNIT_MILES      = 69.0;

/**
 * @param $query
 * @param $lat
 * @param $lng
 * @param $radius numeric
 * @param $units string|['K', 'M']
 */
public function scopeNearLatLng($query, $lat, $lng, $radius = 10, $units = 'K')
{
    $distanceUnit = $this->distanceUnit($units);

    if (!(is_numeric($lat) && $lat >= -90 && $lat <= 90)) {
        throw new Exception("Latitude must be between -90 and 90 degrees.");
    }

    if (!(is_numeric($lng) && $lng >= -180 && $lng <= 180)) {
        throw new Exception("Longitude must be between -180 and 180 degrees.");
    }

    $haversine = sprintf('*, (%f * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(%f)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(%f - lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(%f)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))) AS distance',
        $distanceUnit,
        $lat,
        $lng,
        $lat
    );

    $subselect = clone $query;
    $subselect
        ->selectRaw(DB::raw($haversine));

    // Optimize the query, see details here:
    // http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

    $latDistance      = $radius / $distanceUnit;
    $latNorthBoundary = $lat - $latDistance;
    $latSouthBoundary = $lat + $latDistance;
    $subselect->whereRaw(sprintf("lat BETWEEN %f AND %f", $latNorthBoundary, $latSouthBoundary));

    $lngDistance     = $radius / ($distanceUnit * cos(deg2rad($lat)));
    $lngEastBoundary = $lng - $lngDistance;
    $lngWestBoundary = $lng + $lngDistance;
    $subselect->whereRaw(sprintf("lng BETWEEN %f AND %f", $lngEastBoundary, $lngWestBoundary));

    $query
        ->from(DB::raw('(' . $subselect->toSql() . ') as d'))
        ->where('distance', '<=', $radius);
}

/**
 * @param $units
 */
private function distanceUnit($units = 'K')
{
    if ($units == 'K') {
        return static::DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETERS;
    } elseif ($units == 'M') {
        return static::DISTANCE_UNIT_MILES;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unknown distance unit measure '$units'.");
    }
}
```

This can be used as such:

```
        $places->NearLatLng($lat, $lng, $radius, $units);
        $places->orderBy('distance');
```

The SQL generated, will look approximately like this:

```
select
  *
from
  (
    select
      *,
      (
        '111.045' * DEGREES(
          ACOS(
            COS(
              RADIANS('45.5088')
            ) * COS(
              RADIANS(lat)
            ) * COS(
              RADIANS('-73.5878' - lng)
            ) + SIN(
              RADIANS('45.5088')
            ) * SIN(
              RADIANS(lat)
            )
          )
        )
      ) AS distance
    from
      `places`
    where lat BETWEEN 45.418746  AND 45.598854
      and lng BETWEEN -73.716301 AND -73.459299
  ) as d
where `distance` <= 10
order by `distance` asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use manual pagination as `having` behaving peculiar with pagination class.

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select('posts.*', DB::raw($haversineSQL . ' as distance'))
    ->having('distance', '<=', $distance)
    ->get();

// Items per page
$perPage = 10;
$totalItems = count($posts);
$totalPages = ceil($totalItems / $perPage);

$page = Input::get('page', 1);

if ($page > $totalPages or $page < 1) {
    $page = 1;
}

$offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

$posts = array_slice($posts, $offset, $perPage);

$posts = Paginator::make($posts, $totalItems, $perPage);


dd($posts);
```

Comment: This is going to waste a lot of memory by fetching every row from the database.