# Querying count from Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, count, laravel-5.6

I've got a query in eloquent correctly calculating the count as it should here:

```
$query = A::withCount(
        ['bs' =>
            function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($from) {
                    $query->whereDate('start', '<', $from)
                        ->whereDate('end', '>', $from);
                })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($to) {
                    $query->whereDate('start', '<', $to)
                        ->whereDate('end', '>', $to);
                })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                    $query->whereDate('start', '>', $from)
                        ->whereDate('end', '<', $to);
                });
        }])
        ->whereBetween('cmp1', [$min_cmp1, $max_cmp1])
        ->whereBetween('cmp2', [$min_cmp2, $max_cmp2])
        ->where('cmp3', '<=', $request->cmp3)
        ->where('cmp4', '<=', $request->cmp4)
        ->with('more_relations');

    return AResource::collection($query->paginate(5));
```

This goes to an API Controller. I use this for frontend pagination with Vue. I want to use the count to filter out all `A`'s with a `bs_count` of 0, however chaining a where clause does not work as it is an aggregate, and it returns an error for not finding a column named `bs_count`. The solution, I found out, would be to use a `having` clause. I found this code, but when I try to convert it, it doesn't work, returning the same error, not finding a column named `bs_count`.

```
DB::table('bs')
->select('*', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as bs_count'))
->groupBy('a_id')
->having('bs_count', '=' , 0);
```

This is without adding the extra query on the count, as I wanted to try this to see if it works first, which it doesn't.

Is the `having` clause the correct way to go? I think I need to use Eloquent rather than the `DB::table()` syntax as the Resource builder uses the model structure to build the resource response.

In summary, I'm trying to use the count I calculated in my first query, and query against it: `where bs_count = 0`. Is there a way to do this in Laravel and still be able to pass on the results to the API Resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel does have a built-in solution for this, as I discovered. [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence), I found the functions `whereHas()` and `whereDoesntHave()`. These functions allow you pass a closure to filter the rows based on the count it does behind the scenes. How I adapted my previous solution was:

```
$query = A::whereDoesntHave(
    'bs', 
        function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($from) {
                $query->whereDate('start', '<', $from)
                    ->whereDate('end', '>', $from);
            })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($to) {
                $query->whereDate('start', '<', $to)
                    ->whereDate('end', '>', $to);
            })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                $query->whereDate('start', '>', $from)
                    ->whereDate('end', '<', $to);
            });
    )
    ->whereBetween('cmp1', [$min_cmp1, $max_cmp1])
    ->whereBetween('cmp2', [$min_cmp2, $max_cmp2])
    ->where('cmp3', '<=', $request->cmp3)
    ->where('cmp4', '<=', $request->cmp4)
    ->with('more_relations');

return AResource::collection($query->paginate(5));
```

This automatically does a count of `B`'s based on the query passed and only returns rows that have a count of zero, which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `HAVING` clause is the correct way to go.

The problem is that Laravel pagination doesn't natively support `HAVING` clauses.
You have to create the pagniator manually:
[How to use paginate() with a having() clause when column does not exist in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349397/how-to-use-paginate-with-a-having-clause-when-column-does-not-exist-in-table/20945960)

Your test query with `DB` doesn't work because you can't select all columns when grouping:

```
->select('a_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as bs_count'))
```

Comment: How does this work with the custom count I'm using? Will I have to write the count query in raw SQL as well?

Comment: I think you can use the query as it is and just add `->having('bs_count', '=' , 0)` to it.

Comment: I meant the part with the dates, I'm not trying to get the full count of `B`'s, just the `B`'s that satisfy the date query.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand your question. Can you give me more details?

Comment: In your select call, you use `COUNT(*)`, which I do not believe will query only the rows that satisfy the date logic I have in my first snippet. Will I have to write that date logic in the count in raw SQL for this solution to work?

Comment: That was just meant to show how your test query could be fixed.