# How to get custom column from Eloquent model in array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a column that was added to a Eloquent Model using a raw SQL query, but I am unable to get the value back form the model when doing get(). I can print the model out using print_r() and see the value and column added into the [attributes:protected] and [original:protected] fields, but it doesn't return the value when I do get(). I added an appends attribute and accessor method but it returns null.
Ex:

```
$query = $query->select('*', Capsule::raw('(3959 * acos(
                                                         ( cos( radians( ' . $zip['latitude'] . ' ) )
                                                           * cos( radians( latitude ) )
                                                           * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( ' . $zip['longitude'] . ' ) ))
                                                         + ( sin( radians( ' . $zip['latitude'] . ' ) )
                                                             * sin( radians( latitude ) ))
                                                   )
                                       ) AS distance')
                                   )->orderBy('distance');
```

Object:

```
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [zip_id] => 11753
                            [zipcode] => 29210
                            [territory_id] => 41
                            [latitude] => 34.04814020
                            [longitude] => -81.10814000
                            [last_verified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [nextCheck] => 2020-03-16 17:40:50
                            [active] => 1
                            [distance] => 5.8993697166443E-5
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [zip_id] => 11753
                            [zipcode] => 29210
                            [territory_id] => 41
                            [latitude] => 34.04814020
                            [longitude] => -81.10814000
                            [last_verified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [nextCheck] => 2020-03-16 17:40:50
                            [active] => 1
                            [distance] => 5.8993697166443E-5
                        )
```

Returns:

```
    {
        "zip_id": 11753,
        "zipcode": "29210",
        "territory_id": 41,
        "latitude": "34.04814020",
        "longitude": "-81.10814000",
        "last_verified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "nextCheck": "2020-03-16 17:40:50",
        "active": 1,
        "distance": null
    }
```

As a bonus, if any could tell me why I can use the custom column in the orderBy, but not in the where on the model it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. If you remove the appends variable and the accessor method, then it automatically appends it to the object. But I still can't figure out why I can't use distance in the where clause.

I actually found an answer to using the distance in the where clause as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418611/13085761). Short answer, you have to do the computation again in the where clause as the custom column isn't know to the model.